# Reset val of new tr created using javascript

Tags: javascript, clone

I am new to javascript and am stuck, so need help!

By using javascript I am copying a `tr` using clone method. All is fine but when new `tr` is created it takes the val that are copied from first `tr`, so I want to reset the val of new tr. 
Here is my script

```
function addtr(){
    var newElement = $("#bills > tr").first().clone();
    newElement.removeClass("hide").appendTo("#bills").find("input[type='text']").val("");
    newElement.find(".amount").val("");
    newElement.find(".amount_span").html("");

    registerOnChange();
```

Comment: If you can privide a jsfiddle, it is easier to help.

Comment: For as far as I can see, you do what you want: you clone a row (`<tr>`), and you erare all values in that row.
Can you tell us what part isn't working? And a jsfiddle would be nice as well. :)

Comment: Exactly i want to reset the val of new clonned tr. I want that reset() before registerOnChange(), I don't know how to exactly reset val using javascript, So please help.!!

Answer (score -1):

After changing the val you update to table, This will work

```
> function addtr() {
>         var newElement = $("#bills > tr").first().clone();
>         newElement.find(".amount").val("");
>         newElement.find(".amount_span").html("");
>         newElement.removeClass("hide").appendTo("#bills").find("input[type='text']").val("");
>         registerOnChange();
>     }
```

Comment: How does this make a difference?